# Introducing Batch Normalization destroys later training

Tags: python, tensorflow, batch-normalization

I attempted to (unsuccesfully) introduce Batch Normalization in my model which is shown [here](https://github.com/sachinruk/Traffic-Signs/blob/master/Traffic_Sign_Classifier.ipynb). (see from `def LeNet(x)` block onwards in the code. This is the model without BN).

I tried to introduce BN by doing:

```
def conv_layer(x, filters, ksize=3, bn=False, train=False):
    x = tf.layers.conv2d(x, filters, ksize, padding='same',
                            kernel_initializer=tf.contrib.layers.xavier_initializer_conv2d())
    if bn:
        x = tf.layers.batch_normalization(x, training=train)
    x = tf.nn.relu(x)
    x = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(x,2,2)
    return x
```

and for the optimizer doing:

```
with tf.control_dependencies(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)):
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = rate)
    training_operation = optimizer.minimize(loss_operation)
```

**The question is**, even once I have commented out the batch normalization layer, and the `tf.control_dependencies` part, and rerun the training, my accuracy nose dives to around 2% (and remains) whereas before it was in the 70% area.

I am running this on a Jupyter Notebook with tf version 1.3.0. I understand that `tf.control_dependencies` part is required since BN calculates a moving average of things between batches.

So if I break down the questions:

1. Why is the training suffering even after I comment out BN parts.
2. What exactly is the `tf.control_dependencies` doing?
3. Is there anything extra to be done to use BN in tensorflow.

#### Reference:

The BN version is [here](https://github.com/sachinruk/Traffic-Signs/blob/master/Traffic_Sign_Classifier_BN.ipynb):

Answer (score 0):

(1) means there is a bug in your code somewhere.

(2) batch normalization builds, at training time, moving averages of the batch statistics to use at inference time. The control dependencies ensure that the training moving averages are being updated

(3) no